# Weird Object[] casting from PSObject through a function call

Tags: powershell, casting, psobject

I'm currently coding a function able to cast an ADO (EML attachments from Email) into a PSObject. A stub of the code looks like this:

```
function Get-OriginalMailAttributes([__ComObject]$email){
    #.DESCRIPTION Downloads in Temp the attachment and open it.
    # Returns PSObjectwith values.

    #STEP 1: Download EML
    $TEMPFILE = "..."

    if($email.Attachments.Count){
        $attachment=$email.Attachments|?{$_.Filename.endsWith(".eml")} | select -First 1
        $fileName = $TEMPFILE + $(New-Guid | select -exp Guid) + ".eml"
        $attachment.SaveAsFile($fileName)

        #STEP2 : Retrieve EML Objects
        $adoDbStream = New-Object -ComObject ADODB.Stream
        $adoDbStream.Open()
        $adoDbStream.LoadFromFile($fileName)
        $cdoMessage = New-Object -ComObject CDO.Message
        $cdoMessage.DataSource.OpenObject($adoDbStream, "_Stream")

        #STEP 3: Bind values
        $attributes = New-Object PSObject -Property @{
            From = [string]($cdoMessage.Fields.Item("urn:schemas:mailheader:from").Value.toString())
        }

        #STEP 4: Cleanup
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($cdoMessage)
        [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($adoDbStream)
        Remove-Item $fileName

        return $attributes
        # Note that the debugger acknowledge the fact that $attributes is PSObject.
    }
}
```

I'm then calling the function at some point:

```
$sender_raw = Get-OriginalMailAttributes $email
$sender_raw.getType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name     BaseType
-------- -------- ----     --------
True     True     Object[] System.Array

$sender_raw
0
0

From
----
"Bob" <dummy@contoso.com>
$sender_raw.From # Crashes.
```

Where does this behavior come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when you have "extra" values in the output from a function it's because you're calling methods that have return values and not dealing with those values.

.Add() methods are notorious for outputting the index of the item that was added.

To avoid this problem, you have a few options:

- Cast to void:  [void]$collection.Add($item)
- Assign to $null:  $null=$collection.Add($item)
- Pipe to out-null:  $collection.Add($item) | out-null

I don't see any obvious methods in your code, but adding `Write-output 'Before Step 1'` etc. throughout the code should make it clear where the offending statements are.

Comment: Nice and simple troubleshooting methodology, +1. It's hard to reason about what the source might be without seeing the full script (including what's in place of `#STEP 4: Cleanup (...)`)

Comment: @Mike Shepard , Sorry for the fluffy comment, but love your blog.

Comment: Hi @mike Shapard, thanks for your answer, however through debugger this doesn't get right:
Output of function just before Return : neat PSObject 
Output of function after return (=in CLI) : Object[]

There is no intermediate function that could output such side-variables.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Re-added STEP 4, which was just ADO&File clean.

Comment: @moutonjr - I don't understand your comment.  If you sprinkle write-output statements throughout the code, you'll get the values you're already getting as well as "mile-markers" that tell you where in the script the values are being generated.  You will still get an Object[] out, but looking at it you should be able to determine where to suppress the extra values.  Then, remove the extra write-output statements.

Comment: And, we have a winner.  ReleaseComObject() outputs an int.  apply one of the solutions in my answer to those 2 lines in step 4 and you should be golden.

Comment: Thanks, I add it as an answer, As a newbie, I wasn't aware of this strange way to manage outputs by Powershell, that so different than other scripting languages.

Answer (score 0):

This weird behavior comes from multi-returns from PowerShell functions.

```
PS> function f() {
  1+1
  return 4
}

PS> f
2
4
```

In short, if one-liners are returning values, they are added as an `Object[]` array to the output.
While this is a particularly chaotic way to handle return values of a function, my solution on my code will be to redirect output NULL:

```
    stub...
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($cdoMessage) | Out-Null
    [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($adoDbStream) | Out-Null
```

See *[Suppressing return values in PowerShell functions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/suppressing-return-values-in-powershell-functions/)*